# CI/CD PHP app with Webpack on Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy a Laravel + Vue app over an Azure App Service - Web App. It is however very unclear and I cannot find any proper solution inside Microsoft's documentation to get it into working.

#### 'Traditional' deployment workflow

What I typically do to deploy my code (outside CI/CD):

- sync Git repository
- run `composer install`
- run `npm run prod` (which is a shorthand for compiling webpack in my case)
- Done

There is a really easy approach with a Docker container, where in my Dockerfile I just configure `php-apache` image with additionally installed Nodejs (w. NPM).

However I would like to find a solution to use Azure's built-in features to configure this deployment. Is it possible?

*I can use Windows or Linux Web Apps. No difference for me.*

Comment: How's your issue going? Do you wan to use Azure Devops (dev.azure.com/xxx)? Is the following reply helpful?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT so far we are compiling and pushing using Github Actions. This seems like the least complicated solution so far...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use [continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment). For specific operations, you can check the official documentation.

**Recommended reason:**

1. As long as it runs successfully locally and continuously deploys through git, the project can be released, and later updates only need to submit code through git.
2. You can easily view the deployment log in `Action` in git.
3. Simple operation and convenient update

**Steps:**

1. First, ensure that the project is running normally locally, and create web app services on the portal. (Linux is recommended for the `nodejs` program, which can avoid many problems caused by dependencies)
2. According to the official document, in the Deployment Center, select github for release
3. Check the release information of Action on the official github website and wait for the release to be completed

**Note:**

If it is a nodejs program or other language program, if the Linux operating system is used, the Startup Command may need to be configured in the Configuration. If the program cannot be accessed normally after release, then try to set `npx serve -s` (nodejs program, other Language program), and then proceed to restart the webapp.

Comment: This is a solution we previously used, I however do not consider it built-in in terms of azure... No log, status, analysis in Azure dashboard makes it more difficult